# Linq query list contains a list with same order

Tags: c#, linq

Consider we have these three lists:

```
    List<string> l1= new List<string>(){"A","B","C"};
    List<string> l2= new List<string>(){"A","C","B"};

    List<string> l3= new List<string>(){"B","C"};
```

I need LINQ query which say l1 includes l3 but l2 doesn't.

Comment: can there be duplicates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To *respect the order* and account for possible duplicate elements you have to enumerate the sequence, one way of doing it would be to check for each start position in the source enumeration if the other sequence starts here, e.g. using an extension method:

```
public static bool ContainsSequence<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, 
                                       IEnumerable<T> other)
{
    int count = other.Count();

    while (source.Any())
    {
        if (source.Take(count).SequenceEqual(other))
            return true;
        source = source.Skip(1);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Note that this would be O(n<sup>2</sup>) since worst case you have fully enumerate the `other` enumeration for each item in the `source` collection.

Now you can do:

```
List<string> l1 = new List<string>() { "A", "B", "C" };
List<string> l2 = new List<string>() { "A", "C", "B" };
List<string> l3 = new List<string>() { "B", "C" };

bool l1ContainsL2 = l1.ContainsSequence(l2); //returns false
bool l1ContainsL3 = l1.ContainsSequence(l3); //returns true
```

Answer (score 2):

Exclaimer: As BrokenGlass points out, it's not clear what it means that a list contains another. Here, I allow the containing sequence to have additional items in between the items of the contained sequence.

Quick in terms of typing, not too efficient:

```
bool l1contains = l1.Where(x => l3.Contains(x)).ToList().SequenceEqual(l3);
bool l2contains = l2.Where(x => l3.Contains(x)).ToList().SequenceEqual(l3);
```

More efficient - as efficient as it can be, runs in O(m+n) where m, n are lengths of the lists.

```
private static bool ContainsOrdered<T>(IEnumerable<T> containing, IEnumerable<T> contained)
{
    var e1 = containing.GetEnumerator();
    var e2 = contained.GetEnumerator();
    bool hasmore1 = e1.MoveNext();
    bool hasmore2 = e2.MoveNext();

    while (hasmore1 && hasmore2)
    {
        while (hasmore1 && !e1.Current.Equals(e2.Current))
            hasmore1 = e1.MoveNext();
        if (hasmore1) // Currents are equal
        {
            hasmore1 = e1.MoveNext();
            hasmore2 = e2.MoveNext();
        }
    }

    return !hasmore2;
}

bool contains1 = ContainsOrdered(l1, l3);
bool contains2 = ContainsOrdered(l2, l3);
```

Comment: incorrect since it will match e.g. for l1 = `{1,2,4,3}` and l2 = `{1,2,3}`

Comment: @BrokenGlass that's the point, isn't it? Thats what l1 contains l2 means, in my oppinion

Comment: Mhh I understood it to mean only *contiguous* sequence match - but you might be right. OP should clarify

Comment: should be in same order and without gap between elements

Answer (score 1):

Should just be:

```
l1.Intersect(l3).Except(l2);
```

Notes:
depending on the sizes of l2 and l3 the reverse order may be more efficient.
Given your particular values, nothing will be returned since there is nothing in l1 that's not in l3.